# delphi connect to access x64 database

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2009, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

I am running windows 7 x64 enterprise.
I have Office 2010 x64 installed.
I am using Delphi XE2.
I am trying to compile a program under x64 platform.

How do I connect to my Access database (*.accdb) since there is
no provider installed?

If I am not mistaken, there ought to be a Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0 provider
incorporated but it is not. Not even the 12 .0 one (I think Microsoft reverted to the 12 one...).

Now, there's a big dilemma ...I can not use Access under x64 since there is no provider.
And Access 2010 x64 supposedly  produces an 64 database.Result, the database is not readable on x32 system. So, how on earth do I connect to it ?
I tried using Unidac and it connects very nicely to a *.mdb database.How it does that under x64 platform I really do not know. But it works.But since I usually hardcde database connection string, I do not know how to do that for the UniConnection. So if someone knows,please enlighten me ...

Comment: I'm a little confused... Your question says you're using XE2, but your tags are everything else but that version. ???

Comment: theres no xe2 tag ...at least I have not seen one ...

Comment: I downloaded access drivers for office 2007 version. Now I have ACE 12 provider in my dbGo connection. Compiled under x64 platform and it works. But this worries me... 2007 access database is obviously x32 version. so now I have to ship with my x64 application x32 office 2007 access drivers? And probably a x64 redistributable .... This is all very annoying ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I guess this is the answer :
download access 2007 driver and install.